# Visual Paradigm line break at method parameters

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

I have to make a documentation for my program, and that documentation have to contains class diagrams too.

My problem is, some method has too many parameters, and it makes the class diagram very long horizontally. And these large diagrams doesn't fit in the documentation.

Is there any way to break the line of the parameters? (I tried ctrl+enter) So the method will take place two lines, and it won't be that large horizontally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## How to resize the class elements in VP

#### For already existing classes:

- Right click on the class - not on a class element.
- On Popup menu choose Presentation Options -> Configure Class Presentation Options
- Check `Wrap Members` , OK
- Change the width of the class box and be happy.

#### For new classes from now on:

- Tools-> Project Options->Diagramming->Class->Presentation
- Check `Wrap class Member`, OK/Apply.

#### If you don't see some options

Go into Tools -> Application Options -> General -> Environment, check Advanced UI mode, apply and restart the whole application.

You can also divide a line by hand, using ***Alt+Enter***

Comment: If you don't find Project Options and Application Options under Tools look in the Window tab.

Answer (score 3):

The [Visual Paradigm documentation](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/highlight/multilinename.jsp) says to use Ctrl+Enter but on a OS X at least, it is opt+return.

Note that experience has shown that if you hold down opt too long before pressing return it will activate a menu shortcut mode*.  When this happens it also leaves edit mode so hitting return at that point has no effect.

So on OS X be sure to hit return immediately after pressing down opt.

You can change the key sequence for line breaks on OS X by going to Windows -> Application Options -> Diagramming, and changing the drop-down value for "Create new line key".

*I tried several different Google searches to find the Visual Paradigm documentation that explains this "mode" but didn't have any luck.  I invented the term "menu shortcut mode"  to describe it.

Comment: Now it's just Enter (v16 - no need to define a hot-key).